# tell dnf how to reference an installed library

Tags: fedora, dnf

I'm trying to install Sprite Illuminator on my fedora, originally there's not RPM so i just converted a .deb file to rpm using alien. then, i tried to install the rpm using dnf but i was getting this message:

```
Error: nothing provides libHQX.so.1.0.0()(64bit) needed by spriteilluminator-1.3.1-2.x86_64
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages)
```

After that, i searched the library, compile and installed it using the normal way (make), but when i try to install sprite illuminator, the same error continues, what can i do to tell dnf where the library is?

Answer (score 0):

Forget the RPM.

1. Extract the deb file. You will have two files: *data.tar.xz* and *control.tar.gz*

   ```
   $ ls
   data.tar.xz control.tar.gz
   ```
2. Extract the *data.tar.gz*. It will create a folder named *data* who contains an '*usr*' folder and some subfolders
3. Copy this folder inside /usr

   ```
   $ cd data
   $ cd usr
   $ sudo cp -R * /usr/
   ```

And SpriteIlluminator will be available and working

Comment: I must delete my answer, tomas?